Proper way to send "unprompted" Whatsapp messages
I'm working on a project in my university and one of the requirements would be to send alerts to users on Whatsapp when some conditions are met. The end goal is Whatsapp as we aim to make the alerts as accessible as possible and Whatsapp is the most used instant messaging app in our country.
Does the Meta API offer some way to send messages first? I could only find information on replying to users who have messaged first (and in the last 48 hours) and that would not be what I want as sometimes you could go weeks without an alert being raised. I thought of using third party clients like wuzapi but I feel there are high chances of having the Whatsapp account and phone number banned.

The WhatsApp Business API allows businesses to initiate a conversation only within the 24-hour "Customer Service Window" after a user has sent a message.
This means you can't just send unsolicited alerts to users; they have to opt in first and reinitiate contact periodically if required.
You could take a look at public repos on github such as https://github.com/netflie/whatsapp-cloud-api
